# Программа не читает emails

Tags: java, javamail

Программа выдает null pointer exception когда я пытаюсь вывести n, то есть она не находит письма в папке INBOX, хотя они там есть.

```java
String hostval = "pop.gmail.com";
String mailStrProt = "pop3";
String uname = "*email address*";
String pwd = "*password*";
Properties propvals = new Properties();
propvals.put("mail.pop3.host", hostval);
propvals.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
propvals.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
Session emailSessionObj = Session.getDefaultInstance(propvals);
Store storeObj = emailSessionObj.getStore("pop3s");
storeObj.connect(hostval, uname, pwd);
Folder emailFolderObj = storeObj.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolderObj.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
boolean flag = true;
Message[] messageobjs = emailFolderObj.getMessages();
int n = messageobjs.length;
```

Comment: Пройдитесь дебаггером и проверьте каждый шаг, чтобы найти проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно включить доступ к почтовому ящику стороннему ПО.

См. настройки своего аккаунта [gmail](https://mail.google.com/):

- В правом верхнем углу нажиаем **Settings ⚙ ⇒ See all  settings**.
- Выбираем закладку **Forwarding and POP/IMAP**.
- Выбираем: Enable POP for **all mail** (even mail that's already been downloaded)

[image]

- Или можно выбрать вторую: Enable POP for **mail that arrives from now on** чтобы не получать архивные сообщения.

---

См: [Read Gmail messages on other email clients using POP - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828)